# Excel - COUNTIF for multi column data set with filterable criterium

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a 14 column range of survey data presented in 1's, 0's and "null". In another column, I have company names for which the survey was submitted. I want to count the number of 1's (satisfied), 0's (unsatisfied) and nulls (no answer), and then average the satisfaction rate, for each company name.

For example, on the Grand Total row of my pivot table, I am counting all satisfactory marks with =COUNTIF(Table1[[Q1]:[Q14]],1) but I can't figure out how to limit the count to rows with a specific company name.

*edit*

Here is a screenshot of the sheet I am trying to describe. http://imgur.com/tWwRvov

With Linga’s COUNTIFS suggestion, I wrote it as  `=COUNTIFS(Table1[[Q1]:[Q14]],1,Table1[Company Name],”Company1”)` and get a #VALUE error.

I believe the error is because the number of cells in the 2 ranges don’t align, so I also tried including each Q column as a separate criteria range like:

=COUNTIFS(Table1[Q1],1,Table1[Q2],1,…Table1[Company Name],”Company1”).

The formula validated but the count is not correct.

Comment: You should show the data table, img or something more useful to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]After seeing your snap hope you have to use **SUMIF** formula. Please see the snap for your reference first you need to sum each rows data, then use this formula

```js
=SUMIF(Table1[Comp.Name],"Comp.Name",Table1[Sum])
```

Syntax:

**=SUMIF(criteria_range,criteria,sum_range)**